# Webpack; how to import css dynamically

Tags: javascript, css, webpack

After searching the web I cannot find a straight answer so my question is: Is it possible in webpack to import css files dynamically like so :

```
if(foo){
  import 'mobile.css'
} else {
  import 'desktop.css'
}
```

I tried this and it does not work; is there a workaround or special webpack module or else ?

Comment: romanoff's answer here might give you and idea https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/189

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for me:

```
const foo = false;
if (foo) {
  require("./mobile.css");
} else {
  require("./desktop.css");
}
```

Also you can use the [dynamic import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Dynamic_Imports):

```
const foo = false;
if (foo) {
  import("./mobile.css");
} else {
  import("./desktop.css");
}
```

See: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-hrvzy9?file=index.js