# Load CSS dynamicaly with WebPack

Tags: javascript, html, css, webpack

I would like to create a single-page web app where the user can change the CSS theme. I'm using Webpack.

Here is the html with two buttons for the tests:

```
<button id="dark">Dark</button>
<button id="light">Light</button>
```

Here is my JS file:

```
import './assets/css/style.css';

document.getElementById('dark').addEventListener('click', () => {
    import './assets/css/themes/dark.css';
})

document.getElementById('light').addEventListener('click', () => {
    import './assets/css/themes/light.css';
})
```

Webpack returns the following error

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js 5:4
Module parse failed: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level (5:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| 
| document.getElementById('dark').addEventListener('click', () => {
>     import './assets/css/themes/dark.css';
| })
```

I already read the following ressources:

- ['import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37902849/import-and-export-may-only-appear-at-the-top-level)
- https://lawrencewhiteside.com/courses/webpack-beyond-the-basics/dynamic-css-chunk-loading/
- [Webpack; how to import css dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65145609/webpack-how-to-import-css-dynamically)

But the solutions are not suited for my issue.
I understand that I can't import somewhere else than top level. But I don't understand how to load css dynamicaly with Webpack. Should I copy the CSS themes in the dist folder and write my own JS code to load apply the CSS?

Comment: Use dynamic imports like `import('.file.css')` instead of the import statement